# Error apt-key(8) en instalación de docker

Tags: linux, docker, terminal

Estoy tratando de instalar docker en kubuntu 20.10 en el momento en el que ingreso la llave pública me sale este error:

> Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias maneras de instalarlo en versiones de ubuntu (Focal > 20.04) segun se indica en la documentación: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Puedes intentar instalarlo usando el script descargable

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sudo sh get-docker.sh
```

EDIT:

Para completar la respuesta, el mensaje esta diciendo que ya no se debe usar apt-key para manejar claves. Se debe manejar desde la carpeta `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` donde residen las claves .gpg/.asc, ya sea para agregar, quitar o modificarlas. Por ello, sugiero para este error en particular que se instale docker usando otra opcion (dicha opcion debe ser actualizada para reflejar los cambios recientes en `apt-key`). Del manual:

> Tenga en cuenta que una distribución no necesita y de hecho no debe
> usar este comando más largo y en su lugar enviar archivos de
> claves en el directorio /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ directamente ya que
> esto evita una dependencia de gnupg y es más fácil administrar las
> claves simplemente agregando y eliminando archivos para los encargados
> del mantenimiento y los usuarios.
> http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt-key.8.html#commands

Comment: Esta respuesta, aunque incompleta, da con una solución. ¿Por qué el voto negativo?

Answer (score -2):

Tuve un problema similar al momento de instalar Brave, según los foros de la comunidad solo hace falta continuar con los pasos de instalación debería funcionar... a mi me funciono con Brave, puede que con Docker también funcione